# Rails 3 reset session using devise

Tags: session, ruby-on-rails-3, devise

I am developing a Rails3 application using Devise for authentication. In the course of the workflow, data like patient_id is stored in the session. However, when the user log's out, the session needs to be cleared. I am unable to figure out how to reset session data since Devise handles users login / logout and I not having control over it.

How to handle this situation?

Comment: I'm using Devise and it seems like it automatically resets sessions on logout. Realize this is old an older post- did Devise change behavior since you asked the question, or am I missing something?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Overwrite Devise::SessionsController like this:

```
class SessionsController < Devise::SessionsController
  respond_to :html
  def destroy
    super
    reset_session
  end
end
```

Don't forget to move the devise views to the right place (views/devise/sessions to views/sessions) and modify the devise route to point to your controller. For example:

```
devise_for :users, :controllers => { :sessions => "sessions" }
```

See the devise docs on github for more details or the link posted by Bill.

Comment: Thank you, the above technique should work. It is cleaner than what I am currently having as a solution: https://gist.github.com/735857. This again proves my inability to go through the docs properly. I'll be moving to your solution.

Comment: Maybe I am doing something wrong, but I needed to log a user out and send them to a new page ... so just "reset_session" worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you'd have to over ride the devise controllers, there's a good post here on that:

[Devise, CanCan and customizing devise controllers](http://www.tonyamoyal.com/2010/07/28/rails-authentication-with-devise-and-cancan-customizing-devise-controllers/)