# Devise: call method on sessions#destroy

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, devise

I was wondering what the best way to add extra functionality to Devise's session#destroy action would be.

To give some context, I'm making a website where Users have Carts, and when the user's session either times out or he logs out, I want his Cart to be labeled as inactive.

I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3565952/rails-3-reset-session-using-devise) but I'm a bit hesitant to override the Devise controller, as it seems a bit messy...

Are there any other ways to set this Cart to inactive when a user's session is destroyed?

Comment: It's totally ok to override a Devise controller. You may be afraid to delve deeper into this stuff but it's normal to override Devise to achieve extra functionality. When in doubt, use the source, Luke.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I do suggest you derive your controller from devise and hook onto the action, so you can safely keep away from devise's internals.

```
# routes.rb
devise_for :users, :controllers => { :sessions => "sessions" } # etc

# sessions_controller.rb
class SessionsController < Devise::SessionsController

  after_filter :set_cart_inactive!, :only => :destroy
  def set_cart_inactive!
    unless user_signed_in? # logout successful?
       # code here
    end
  end

end
```

Comment: This looks good. My only question is why would you need the `unless` clause? Shouldn't users always be signed out after sessions#destroy?